# Can I apply polyurethane to my hardwood floors one room at a time?

Tags: hardwood-floor, polyurethane

I have hardwood floors on almost all of my floors.  Most rooms have large (5') openings with no doors or thresholds.  When I start applying the polyurethane, is there anyway to do one room at a time or do I have to get the furniture out of the dining room, living room, office, and front hall and seal all floors at the same time?  I don't have any place to move all the furniture too, even if I stacked it vertically in the kitchen and porch.

Answer (score 1):

It make take some work to feather the edges where one room meets another, but you *should* be able to do one room at a time. At worst you might wind up with a slight line across the threshold, which nobody but you would ever notice....

Comment: so I should definitely not stop in a straight line and then take the finest grit to sand the random line created?  What is this feathering technique?  Thanks

Comment: Feathering: Taper the thickness off as you reach the threshhold, so that when the two successve rooms' finishing overlaps the total build is about the same as what's happening in each individual room. Of course this is less of an issue if you're using a transparent finish (water-based poly) than if you're using one that has a bit of color to it (oil-based, or a shellac sealer layer, either of which shifts the color toward the yellow end of things). Outside of that, follow manufacturer's instructions for successive layers (usually a light sanding between coats unless you are "hot-coating")

Comment: The thresholds should have areas of completely overlapping streaks, just don't leave a puddle anywhere. Don't dip the applicator anymore to leave streaks as you undercut into the next room a little. *Lifting off* at the end of a stroke helps feather. @Betsy